# How to update selected records in one transaction with Entity Framework?

Tags: sql-server, multithreading, entity-framework, concurrency, transactions

I am using SQL Server. My case looks like this:

1. I have a table `Messages`. The table has a column `MessageStatusId`
2. I have a couple of services which have access this database
3. Periodically each service selects messages with status `New` and handles these messages somehow
4. The services select messages like:

   ```
   await DbContext.Set<Message>()
                  .Where(m => m.MessageStatusId == MessageStatusEnum.New)
                 .ToListAsync();
   ```
5. After processing, the service updates message status

I don't want the services to select the same set of records. So I need to update message status to `InProcess`. How to implement this in one transaction with Entity Framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement pessimistic locking to ensure only one worker is accessing the table at a time, however it is very important to keep the table access as short as absolutely possible to avoid deadlocks between clients. I would suggest fetching a limited number of rows per request:

```
var options = new TransactionOptions
{
   IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.Serializable,
   Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 10)
};

var messageIds = new List<int>();

using(var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, options))
{
    using (var context = new MessageDbContext())
    {
        var messages = context.Messages
            .Where(x => x.MessageStatusId == MessageStatusEnum.New)
            .OrderBy(x => x.MessageDate)
            .Take(100)
            .ToList();

       foreach(var message in messages)
           message.MessageStatusId = MessageStatusEnum.InProgress;

       context.SaveChanges();
       messageIds = messages.Select(x => x.MessageId).ToList();
    }
    scope.Commit();
}
```

My recommendations here would be:

- Separate this Message entity off into a bounded DbContext that serves just message checking/status updating, nothing else. This message entity could just be MessageId and MessageStatusId for this operation and others to check on a message status /w pessimistic locking.
- Use a synchronous call, faster than async.
- Fetch the rows, mark them off as in-progress and grab their IDs then commit the status change. You can read them with optimistic locking afterwards to process at your leisure and avoid deadlocking.
- Limit the # of rows queried to avoid surprises if there happen to be a significant backlog. (10, 100, whatever is reasonable)

Comment: Thank you a lot for detail explanation. This solutions works for me. I will adapt it for my needs.